# Migrate home tabs from one org to another

Tags: migration, home-page-layout

I'm in the process of migrating all the configurations from a dev org to an enterprise account.

I followed a standard migration procedure with the eclipse Force plugin, it was not straightforward and I'm inspecting both org interfaces to find out differences.

I found that the tabs that I created for the homepage of my dev. admin user are not present in the new environment, I wonder if it is because they are attached to a user rather than to a profile. Is that the reason or there should be an automatic way to migrate it? Is there a way to move the tab configuration to a higher level entity (a profile or a role, etc)?

Thanks

Dev

[image]

Enterprise sandbox

[image]

Comment: Tabs are associated with apps and have visibility by Profile